# post request works with postman but not in browser, via axios

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

I am working on a MERN app. When I make a post request via Postman to `"/collections"`, I get the expected response, and the database is updated with a new document. When I make the request in the browser, the code runs, but the database does not get a new document. Here is my submit handler (reactjs):

```
handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await axios.post("/collections", this.state.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
    this.props.history.push("/collections");
  };
```

The last line of this code runs when I submit the relevant form, and my browser is returned to `"/collections"`. The code doesn't throw or log any errors, but the submit does not create a new document, as revealed by mongodb Compass. Also strange, this code was modified from another part of the app that is working fine in the browser:

```
handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios.post("/entries", this.state.data);
    this.props.history.push("/entries");
  };
```

This works just fine, but the post to `"/collections"` does not. Any help?

For reference, here's the post route in node:

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newCollection = await Collection.create(req.body);
    res.send(newCollection);
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: You should open the dev tools in the browser and tell us what is happening with the request

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pedro Brost, I figured it out. Under "Network", in Dev Tools, I was getting a validation error due to the way my mongoose schema was set up. I didn't know "Network" was a thing in Dev Tools.